# Is it possible to have the in-call status bar go over content instead of moving everything down?

Tags: swift

I have a function that recognizes when the status bar height is about to change. I just need to know if it's possible to have the extended status bar overlap content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe so. The HIG states that your app must be able to handle the double height status bar and adjust itself automatically.